# SQL loop over all days in datetime range and calculate a value for every day in the range

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**Updated: Solution is at the bottom of the answer!**

**Title was: SQL query with 'WITH' runs outside stored procedure, but not as the body of stored procedure**

On SQL Server 2008

Working SQL query:

```
declare @start datetime = '01 jan 2012'
declare @end   datetime = '31 dec 2012'
declare @articleId int = 4

;WITH amonth(day) as
(
    select @start as day
        union all
    select day + 1
        from amonth
        where day < @end
)

(select total=(
    select SUM(UnitPrice * NewQuantity) as Value from InventoryBatch invBatches
    inner join
    (select * from
     (SELECT
          TOP 100 PERCENT
          [B].[InventoryBatchId] AS [InventoryBatchId],
          RANK() over (partition by [B].[InventoryBatchId] order by [B].[MutationDate] desc) AS [MutationDate],
          [B].[MutationDate] as [RealDate],
          [B].[Id],
          [B].NewQuantity
        FROM
          [InventoryBatchHistory] [B]
        WHERE
          ([B].[ArticleId] = @articleId AND [B].[DeliveryDate] <= amonth.day)
        GROUP BY
          [B].[InventoryBatchId], [MutationDate], [B].Id, B.NewQuantity) INV where MutationDate = 1) latest
          on invBatches.Id = latest.InventoryBatchId),
 amonth.day
    from amonth
    left join #t on #t.DT = amonth.day 
group by amonth.day ) OPTION (MAXRECURSION 400)
```

Gives me a list of calculated totals for each day, nice.

Now I want to reuse this as a StoredProcedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTotalQuantityForArticleRange](
    @articleId INT,
    @start DATETIME,
    @end DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN

WITH amonth(day) as
(
    select @start as day
        union all
    select day + 1
        from amonth
        where day < @end
)

(select total=(
    select SUM(UnitPrice * NewQuantity) as Value from InventoryBatch invBatches
    inner join
    (select * from
     (SELECT
          TOP 100 PERCENT
          [B].[InventoryBatchId] AS [InventoryBatchId],
          RANK() over (partition by [B].[InventoryBatchId] order by [B].[MutationDate] desc) AS [MutationDate],
          [B].[MutationDate] as [RealDate],
          [B].[Id],
          [B].NewQuantity
        FROM
          [InventoryBatchHistory] [B]
        WHERE
          ([B].[ArticleId] = @articleId AND [B].[DeliveryDate] <= amonth.day)
        GROUP BY
          [B].[InventoryBatchId], [MutationDate], [B].Id, B.NewQuantity) INV where MutationDate = 1) latest
          on invBatches.Id = latest.InventoryBatchId),
 amonth.day
    from amonth 
    left join #t on #t.DT = amonth.day
group by amonth.day) OPTION (MAXRECURSION 400)

END



GO
```

Called as:

```
declare @start1 datetime = '01 jan 2012'
declare @end1   datetime = '31 dec 2012'


exec GetTotalQuantityForArticleRange 4, @start = @start1, @end = @end1
```

And I consistently get a NULL result. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

**Added from suggestion by drdigit**

When using

```
WITH amonth(day) as ( select @start as day union all select day + 1 from amonth where day < @end ) SELECT * FROM amonth OPTION (MAXRECURSION 400);
```

as the first line in the body of the SP, I indeed get returned the dates I am seeking for. What I yet fail to comprehend how this won't work when setting the calculated values.

All thanks thus far!

**Working solution:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTotalQuantityForArticleRange](
    @articleId INT,
    @start DATETIME,
    @end DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN

WITH amonth(day) as 
( 
    select @start as day
        union all
    select day + 1
        from amonth
        where day < @end
)
SELECT total=(
    select SUM(UnitPrice * NewQuantity) as Value from InventoryBatch invBatches
    inner join
    (select * from
     (SELECT
          TOP 100 PERCENT
          [B].[InventoryBatchId] AS [InventoryBatchId],
          RANK() over (partition by [B].[InventoryBatchId] order by [B].[MutationDate] desc) AS [MutationDate],
          [B].[MutationDate] as [RealDate],
          [B].[Id],
          [B].NewQuantity
        FROM
          [InventoryBatchHistory] [B]
        WHERE
          ([B].[ArticleId] = @articleId AND [B].[DeliveryDate] <= amonth.day)
        GROUP BY
          [B].[InventoryBatchId], [MutationDate], [B].Id, B.NewQuantity) INV where MutationDate = 1) latest
          on invBatches.Id = latest.InventoryBatchId), * FROM amonth OPTION (MAXRECURSION 400); 

END



GO
```

Comment: The two date ranges in your trials are different. This is confusing. Do you get different results when using the same date ranges?

Comment: Title is not accurate. Your specific CTE (with) works the same as plain T-SQL query and within a stored prodecure for the same date range. You can vefiry it by (@ is changed to _ due to comment limitiations):

WITH amonth(day) as
(
    select _start as day
        union all
    select day + 1
        from amonth
        where day < _end
)
SELECT * FROM amonth;

Comment: I am incredibly relieved to report that the stored procedure is working due to your suggestions, however still working on digesting the real difference so I can update the question accordingly for further reference. Maybe you can summarize it as an answer so I can mark your contribution as an answer?